# How to fix error with sample code for MFC tooltips?

Tags: c++, mfc, tooltip

I get this error when compiling the following source [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164067.aspx):

> Error 1   error C2440: 'static_cast' :
>   cannot convert from 'UINT (__thiscall
>   CStaticLink::* )(CPoint)' to 'LRESULT
>   (__thiscall CWnd::*
>   )(CPoint)'    e:\development\tooltips\cqa0311\statlink.cpp    28

The line of code is for the ON_WM_NCHITTEST below

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStaticLink, CStatic)
    ON_WM_NCHITTEST()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
    ON_WM_SETCURSOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I am not sure what MFC voodoo I have to do to get this to compile.  Am I out of luck?  I guess this was built with some different version of MFC?  I am using VS2008.

(I want to have tooltips for my menu items as described on that webpage.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/412524/on-wm-nchittest-vs2008):

> Thanks for the report. I investigated and found that this change was by design, in MFC for Visual Studio 2005. This introduced a source incompatibility, so you will need to update your OnNcHitTest method to return an LRESULT instead of a UINT.
>
> Pat Brenner
>   Visual C++ Libraries Development

Now [OnNcHitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923b34d9%28VS.80%29.aspx) should be declared as follows:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnNcHitTest(
   CPoint point 
);
```

Comment: Now I feel pretty dumb, but thanks.  The macro threw me off the scent there.  ON_WM_NCHITTEST() - gosh, how I despise MFC and all that macro voodoo.